# PL/SQL:How I can select the rows from the 3 tables and rearrange the rows by using particular column value?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

Vehicle Passing Summary table structure

```
    PsngSmry_ID(Number),Vehicle_iD(Number),PsngSmryTime(datetime)
```

Vehicle table structure

```
    Vehicle_iD(Number),VehicleName(VarChar2),VehicleType(VarChar2)
```

Here Vehicle_iD is the Primary Key

Equipment Table Structure

```
    Eqpmt_id(Number),Vehicle_iD(Number),EqpmtName(VarChar2),EqpmtType(VarChar2)
```

Here Eqpmt_id is the Primary Key and Vehicle_iD is the foreign Key

Equipment Component Table Structure

```
    Eqpmt_Cmpnt_id(Number) ,Eqpmt_id(Number),EqpmtCmpntName(VarChar2),EqpmtCmpntName(VarChar2),Parent_Eqpmnt_ID(Number)
```

Here Eqpmt_Cmpnt_id is the Primary Key and Eqpmt_id is the foreign Key

The rows in the Vehicle Passing Summary table

```
PsngSmry_ID Vehicle_ID  PsngSmryTime
111111      80986246    2010/10/11
111112      80986247    2010/10/12
111113      80986248    2010/10/10
```

The rows in the Vehicle Table

```
Vehicle_iD  VehicleName VehicleType
80986246        Lorry       Four Wheeler
80986247        Van     Four Wheeler
80986248        Bus     Four Wheeler
```

The rows in the Equipment Table:

```
Eqpmt_id    Vehicle_iD  EqpmtName       EqpmtType
109846      80986246        2 Axle Lorry        CAR
    109821      80986246        4 Axle Lorry        CAR
    109825      80986246        4 Axle Lorry        CAR
109562      80986247        2 Axle VAn      CAR
    109555      80986247        3 Axle VAn      CAR
    109777      80986247        3 Axle VAn      CAR
109587      80986248        2 Axle Bus      CAR
```

The rows in the Equipment Component Table :

```
Eqpmt_Cmpnt_id Eqpmt_id EqpmtCmpntName Parent_Eqpmnt_ID
20904146        109846      Truck             
20904147        109846      Truck
20904148        109846      Axle            20904146
20904159        109846      Axle            20904146
20904167        109846      Wheel           20904148
20904177        109846      Wheel           20904148
20904185        109846      Wheel           20904159
20904325        109846      Wheel           20904159
20904188        109846      Axle            20904147
20904189        109846      Axle            20904147
20904195        109846      Wheel           20904188
20904196        109846      Wheel           20904188
20904197        109846      Wheel           20904189
20904398        109846      Wheel           20904189
10904146        109562      Truck             
10904147        109562      Truck
10904148        109562      Axle            10904146
10904159        109562      Axle            10904146
10904167        109562      Wheel           10904148
10904177        109562      Wheel           10904148
10904185        109562      Wheel           10904159
10904325        109562      Wheel           10904159
10904188        109562      Axle            10904147
10904189        109562      Axle            10904147
10904195        109562      Wheel           10904188
10904196        109562      Wheel           10904188
10904197        109562      Wheel           10904189
10904398        109562      Wheel           10904189
```

Note : In Equipment Component Table,the hierarchy will be Truck-->Axle-->Wheel.So

1.the Parent_Eqpmnt_ID of Axle is Truck's Eqpmt_Cmpnt_id.
2.the Parent_Eqpmnt_ID of Wheel is Axle's Eqpmt_Cmpnt_id.

Now I want to write the store procedure which will take "PsngSmry_ID(Number)" as input and the o/p will be in the format :

```
Eqpmt_Cmpnt_id Eqpmt_id EqpmtCmpntName Parent_Eqpmnt_ID
20904146        109846      Truck   
20904148        109846      Axle            20904146
20904167        109846      Wheel           20904148
20904177        109846      Wheel           20904148    
20904159        109846      Axle            20904146
20904185        109846      Wheel           20904159
20904325        109846      Wheel           20904159
20904147        109846      Truck
20904188        109846      Axle            20904147
20904195        109846      Wheel           20904188
20904196        109846      Wheel           20904188
20904189        109846      Axle            20904147
20904197        109846      Wheel           20904189
20904398        109846      Wheel           20904189
10904146        109562      Truck   
10904148        109562      Axle            10904146
10904167        109562      Wheel           10904148
10904177        109562      Wheel           10904148    
10904159        109562      Axle            10904146
10904185        109562      Wheel           10904159
10904325        109562      Wheel           10904159
10904147        109562          Truck
10904188        109562          Axle            10904147
10904195        109562          Wheel           10904188
10904196        109562          Wheel           10904188
10904189        109562          Axle            10904147
10904197        109562          Wheel           10904189
10904398        109562          Wheel           10904189

       **Please add these columns in the o/p **
        1.EqpmtName and EqpmtType from Eqpmt table
        2.VehicleName and Vehicle Type from Vehicle table
        3.PsngSmryTime from PassingSummary table **
```

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: I should note that the Eqpmt_id FK values on Equipment Component doesn't match the referencing table values ( ie, Eqpmt_id on Equipment ), but matches vehicle ids. hmm?

Comment: Each Eqpmnt_ID will have muliple Eqpmnt_Cmpnt_ID.In the above given example,i posted for Only one Eqquipmnt_id. If u have any queries , pls let me know

Comment: What part of my comment didn't you get? You say Eqpmt_id is the FK and yet your table values says it is not.

Comment: sATHYA: wRONGLY POSTED....NOW I EDITED IT.PLS HAVE A LOOK AT IT.

Answer (score 3):

For such questions, you should **always** post the corresponding DDL and DML statements. I am sure anyone willing to answer the question will appreciate such an effort. Also, it would have prevented the foreign key error and probably the -1.

That said... I have constructed such statements:

```
drop table         tq84_equipment_component;
drop table         tq84_equipment;
drop table         tq84_vehicle;

create table       tq84_vehicle (
  vehicle_id       number primary key,
  vehicleName      varchar2(20),
  vehicleType      varchar2(20)
);

create table       tq84_equipment (
  eqpmt_id         number primary key,
  vehicle_id       not null references tq84_vehicle,
  eqpmtName        varchar2(20),
  eqpmtType        varchar2(20)
);

create table       tq84_equipment_component (
  eqpmt_cmpnt_id   number primary key,
  eqpmt_id         not null references tq84_equipment,
  eqpmtCmpntName   varchar2(20),
  parent_eqpmnt_id null references tq84_equipment_component
);


insert into tq84_vehicle values (80986246, 'Lorry', 'Four Wheeler');
insert into tq84_vehicle values (80986247, 'Van'  , 'Four Wheeler');
insert into tq84_vehicle values (80986248, 'Bus'  , 'Four Wheeler');

insert into tq84_equipment values (109846, 80986246, 'Axle Lorry', 'CAR');
insert into tq84_equipment values (109562, 80986247, 'Axle Van',   'CAR');
insert into tq84_equipment values (109587, 80986248, 'Axle Bus',   'CAR');


insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904146, 109846, 'Truck',     null);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904148, 109846, 'Axle' , 20904146);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904167, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904148);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904177, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904148);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904159, 109846, 'Axle' , 20904146);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904185, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904159);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904325, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904159);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904147, 109846, 'Truck',     null);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904188, 109846, 'Axle' , 20904147);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904195, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904188);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904196, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904188);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904189, 109846, 'Axle' , 20904147);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904197, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904189);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (20904398, 109846, 'Wheel', 20904189);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904146, 109562, 'Truck',     null);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904148, 109562, 'Axle' , 10904146);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904167, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904148);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904177, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904148);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904159, 109562, 'Axle ', 10904146);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904185, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904159);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904325, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904159);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904147, 109562, 'Truck',     null);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904188, 109562, 'Axle' , 10904147);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904195, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904188);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904196, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904188);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904189, 109562, 'Axle' , 10904147);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904197, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904189);
insert into tq84_equipment_component values (10904398, 109562, 'Wheel', 10904189);
```

With these data, I believe you're after something like this:

```
select
  eqpmt_cmpnt_id,
  eqpmt_id,
  eqpmtCmpntName
  parent_eqpmnt_id
from
  tq84_equipment_component
start with
  eqpmt_id in (select eqpmt_id 
                from tq84_equipment
               where vehicle_id = 80986246) 
connect by
  prior eqpmt_cmpnt_id = parent_eqpmnt_id
order by 1;
```

**Edit**: changed `eqpmt_id = (select ...` to `eqpmt_id in (select ...`

Comment: Each Vehicle_ID will have no. of equipments...I posted it wrongly...sorry for my mistake...i edited it now...pls have a look

Comment: Actually your query is working fine if i remove the sub query in Start with clause and replaced with 'Eqpmt_id = '109846'.Since the tq84_equipment table will have no. of equipments for each Vehicle_id ,i am receiving this error ----->ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: I have added one more table to the hierarchy i.e Passing summary table .So my Stored procedure the input will be 'PsngSmry_ID'.The o/p to be displayed is also changed. i edited it now.pls have a look at it..provide me the solution if you can....